# Present a ViewController from the AppDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, 3dtouch

I have a 3D Force Touch Action that I set up in my `Info.plist`. Now I want that when the 3D Action is running it presents a view controller that I gave a Storyboard ID and I need to do this in the `AppDelegate`.

I used the `performActionForShortCutItem` function.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, performActionFor shortcutItem: UIApplicationShortcutItem, completionHandler: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
    if let tabVC = self.window?.rootViewController as? UITabBarController {
        if shortcutItem.type == "Hausaufgaben" {
            tabVC.selectedIndex = 1
            tabVC.performSegue(withIdentifier: "gotoHausaufgaben", sender: nil)
        }    
    }        
}
```

Comment: Please provide your code for reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, performActionFor shortcutItem: UIApplicationShortcutItem, completionHandler: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
   if shortcutItem.type == "Hausaufgaben" {
      self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
      let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
      let initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "YOUR PAGE Identifier")
      self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
      self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your Help, it worked but my Navigation Bar Buttons don't seem to work. and I can't navigate through my views and return to other view controllers It seems that I'm Stuck in that view controller

Comment: @user7418615 you can embed your view in a navigation controller and then send your user to that navigation controller

Comment: I did that and it shows now the navigation bar but the buttons don't work. Do I have to load anything more or tell from where i navigated to the NavigationController. Because it seems that im stuck in that view

Comment: @user7418615 because of user come to the app from out of application ...the navigation queue is empty... you can make back button programmatically in viewDidLoad()